# Permanently adding workspace to ROS environment

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) tutorial to create a new ROS package. In step 4 we build the catkin workspace and sourc the setup file and once this is done I can do a `roscd beginner_tutorials`  from anywhere and it will take me to `~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials` brilliant! ...until I close the terminal window and open a new one. Now `roscd <TAB> <TAB>` doesn't show "beginner_tutorials" as an option. If I re-source my setup file i.e. do a `. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` everything works again.

Do I need to source my setup file everytime I open a new terminal window or is there some way to permanently add it to my ROS environment?

I have this `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` at the end of my .bashrc file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303671/permanently-adding-workspace-to-ros-environment/) by [Drkstr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29909/drkstr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're always working with that workspace, you can just add `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` at the end of your `.bashrc`.

---

Originally posted by [Hug](https://answers.ros.org/users/36570/hug/) with karma: 66 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To permanently add it without having to source it all the time, use this: `echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc`

---

Originally posted by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) with karma: 120 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1